# How to use Capybara for IE8 in pure Ruby (without Rails)?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cucumber, capybara

I've been using the following code to test run using Capybara with IE8 in pure Ruby, i.e. NOT a rails app but every time I run the script IE8 pops up but then Firefox pops up and the tests run through Firefox leaving IE8 sitting in the background:

```
$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib')

begin require 'rspec/expectations'; rescue LoadError; end
require 'rubygems'

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'

require 'selenium-webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver.for :internet_explorer
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

require 'cukesalad'
begin require 'rspec/expectations'; rescue LoadError; require 'spec/expectations'; end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too old maybe you can find some useful information from it:

[Run Capybara & Cucumber Features In Internet Explorer On Remote Windows](http://www.johng.co.uk/2010/10/13/run_capybara_and_cucumber_features_in_internet_explorer_on_remote_windows/)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's only for rack based apps and creates an error when trying to use it, as my server is a remote server, ie a non-rack based app.